# Output of building process, followed by Error List (if applicable) in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012

When I used Visual Studio 6 when that was the hot thing, one of the things I loved was that I would hit F7, compile, and watch the output of the build go buy and then be greeted with an error list when complete. I believed this changed in Visual Studio 2005, but I've had enough of it and would like my old way back. Is there a way to tell VS2012 to output the build output and then show the error list if it's applicable?

Sorry if this has been asked before, I checked and didn't see anything.

Comment: AFAIK, `View->Output` or `Ctrl+Alt+O` to view the output messages and then a compile or build works about the same way, but it's been a long time since I looked at VS6 - I could be mistaken.

Comment: On all my builds, this just keeps it on output. It doesn't actually go to the error list.

Comment: You can read the build output? You must be programming C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the Tools -> Options -> Project and Solutions -> Show Output window when build starts

This seems to work for me.

[image: Show Output on build]